# Eliminate gap between columns

Tags: powerbi

How I am able to eliminate gap between columns in column chart like this, I didn't see any property to allow me to configure this:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you set one of the columns as the Legend and the other column as the Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in option to eliminate the gap. Suggest you submit an idea at http://ideas.powerbi.com or make a contribution to the open source repo where our visuals are implemented so you get the feature you'd like: http://www.github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals